# When I call SendKeys method, my driver doesn't update the URL. SeleniumWebDriver, C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I apologize for bothering you this Sunday.
My goal is just navigate through different links by clicking or sending keys and press the enter key.
I'm trying to understand why I can't update the URL when I call the method SendKeys() and press the enter key of a driver.
Let's put the code to be more specific:

```
        IWebDriver d = new FirefoxDriver();
        d.Url = "https://www.google.com/";
        d.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("cheese"+Keys.Enter) ;
        Console.WriteLine(d.Url);
        d.Quit();
        Console.ReadKey();
```

It runs, open the Firefox driver and search the "cheese" word. Also displays the page updated.
But displays in the console:

> https://www.google.com/

Not https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=cheese.

However, if I use, for example, the Click() method, I can get the URL updated. Let me show you by code:

```
        IWebDriver d = new FirefoxDriver();
        d.Url = "https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=cheese";
        d.FindElement(By.TagName("h3")).Click();
        Console.WriteLine(d.Url);
        d.Quit();
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Then, I get the URL updated, and the console displays the URL of the first occurrence. In my case displays:

> https://www.linguee.es/ingles-espanol/traduccion/cheese.html

From now on, I appreciate your attention.
Regards sincerily,
Ivan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you've accepted your own answer but that's not a good approach. What you need to do is to wait for the URL to change.

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
string url = "https://www.google.com";
driver.Url = url;
driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("cheese" + Keys.Enter);
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(d => d.Url != url);
Console.WriteLine(driver.Url);
driver.Quit();
Console.ReadKey();
```

This prints

> https://www.google.com/search?q=cheese&source=hp&ei=XnpzYMOTJou8sAW9wp7gCw&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAYHOIblYFXWyd6H0a0gVNEfONWvFBaymu&oq=cheese&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EANQvgJYxAJgxQJoAHAAeACAAQCIAQCSAQCYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjDutnvoPfvAhULHqwKHT2hB7wQ4dUDCAk&uact=5

Answer (score -1):

After thinking for 3 hours, I realised that I was giving a short time to the driver.
 So I decided to add a pause to let the program run better. I know that it's a bad practice, but now, I know where is the problem.
So the current code is like this:

```
IWebDriver d = new FirefoxDriver();
d.Url = "https://www.google.com/";
d.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("cheese" + Keys.Enter);
Console.ReadKey();
Console.WriteLine(d.Url);
d.Quit();
Console.ReadKey();
```

So when I execute the program, it displays:

> https://www.google.com/search?q=cheese&source=hp&ei=K3VzYP7oMMG55OUPna-hUA&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAYHODO57NNe7OQV7bgk-J-ui7X9cg8TxB&oq=cheese&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCAguELEDEJMCMgUIABCxAzIFCAAQsQMyAggAMgIILjIICC4QsQMQgwEyBQguELEDMgUIABCxAzICCAAyAggAOggIABCxAxCDAToLCAAQsQMQxwEQowI6CwguELEDEIMBEJMCOg4IABCxAxCDARDHARCjAjoECAAQClC8BlixDGDSDWgAcAB4AIABX4gBkgSSAQE2mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwi-qo71m_fvAhXBHLkGHZ1XCAoQ4dUDCAY&uact=5

And works.
Thank you for help.
My doubt is solved.

Comment: You are defeating the purpose of automation by making the user sit at the console, wait for the `.ReadKey()`, and hit <ENTER> in the middle of automation. See my answer for a better way to do this.